# How to load JFrame contains trees

Tags: database, swing, jtree

I am working on a standalone swing application.I have created trees by taking the values form the database.

So now the problem is i want to reload each tree,on database change so that each tree will have the current database tables values.

any type of guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the exact problem? How-to be notified when the db has changed? Or how to reload the tree? Or something else?

Comment: We created a separate tree for Db Connection so any time user can change the connection parameter and save them.Now the connection has been changed so that the value of others tree must be come by the latest database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a job / task / thread to run in background and query the database from time to time and notify all listeners about the changes in the database that anyone is interested in. One of such listeners would be your tree.

However, be careful on how often you hit the database, you may cause performance issues.

Comment: Of course the update of the tree(model) should happen on the EDT and not on that background thread

Comment: That was for the next question :)

Comment: @Dan thanks a lot dan for your useful answer.is there any thing so that i can reload all other tree on database change?

Comment: Use the same approach for any UI piece that needs to reload.